# User unable to add/remove programs through package manager

Tags: permissions

I added a user to my Pi and thought I set him up like the original pi user.  I added him using `adduser -a -G` and assigned him all the groups assigned to pi through `usermod`.

He seems to be able to do everything through the command line using sudo but when he tries to add or remove packages through the package manager it asks for authentication by either root or pi.  The added user is not even displayed as an option.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to add the user to 
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/60-desktop-policy.conf

The contents look like this

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-user:pi;unix-user:0
```

You would modify to look like this

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-user:pi;unix-user:newuser;unix-user:0
```

I did this in addition to adding the user to the sudoer.d list.